# how do you add jquery in a html page as a web resource in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: jquery, html, dynamics-crm

having a lot of trouble with this one. I am trying to run a simple
jquery script inside of an html page to just pop up an alert box.

I have uploaded the jquery library and the json library

I have an html page with the following references and the reference to my jquery script. It is not coming up with the alert however when I embed this html as an iframe.

```
 <SCRIPT src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../jquery1.4.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

I was reading something about relative paths and what have you I have tried

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../Script/jquery1.4.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../Scripts/jquery1.4.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

both.

But its not working.

Comment: I see that there is code in your question when I hit the 'edit' link, but cannot see it here.  Can you format your code so that everyone can read it?  Hint: put 4 spaces in front of each line that you want to be code.

Answer (score 9):

I see two options available to you.

**Option 1: Relative Paths**
Web Resources can point to each other via relative paths. So, it really depends on the "Name" of your html web resource and your jquery web resources.

The "Name" of a web resource cannot be changed after it has been created. So, you want to pay close attention to this. (You can always delete it and create it again with a new name, though.) This Name value can have a path in it.

For example, your jQuery library web resource might have a Name of "/Scripts/jquery.js". If you html page (that your iframe points to) has a name of "/Pages/mypage.html", then that html page must reference the jQuery library like so:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

It has to go up a level to get out of the Pages folder, then down into the Scripts folder, and hits the jquery.js file. You can think of this as a real file system, as if you were working with a regular ASP.NET site.

**Option 2: CDN**
Google (and other networks) host libraries like jQuery on their Content Delivery Networks (CDN). They designed these to be extremely fast and reliable. If you don't mind requiring a connection to the internet for your functionality to work, you can link directly to jquery on Google's CDN.

To do this, change your script tag for jQuery to this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```