# click event on an image inside a span is not working

Tags: jquery, html

Can I put an image inside a span and give click event to the span using jQuery. Here it is not working in my code have any idea.

```
<span id="removeNewTime" class="removeTime">
    <img src="Images/close button.png" alt="close" />
</span>
```

jQuery code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".removeTime").click(function(){
            alert("hello");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what's the error infomation?

Comment: check jquery is included correctly,put alert inside ready

Answer (score 1):

It is work you might need to [include jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/), This post tell how to [add jQuery on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232968/how-do-you-add-jquery-in-a-html-page-as-a-web-resource-in-dynamics-crm-2011).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PPxX2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".removeTime").click(function(){
     alert("hello");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Either set your span's CSS to `display:block;` or replace the span with a `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jquery library included before any doc ready function applied:

**see the working fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/87Laj/

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".removeTime").click(function(){
      alert("hello");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included jquery in the head section of your file. As the code is working fine.

For simplicity always use `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

This will ensure you always have the latest jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem in jquery file, which is required to jquery code to be working.

Check the working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/SEBDU/2/)**

Small improvements to js code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".removeTime").on('click', function(){
         alert("hello");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working
Notice some points in your code

1) Don't forget to add latest jquery file like
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js to your code.

2) Download from http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

some times i do  like this its dosnt work,

then i try this (if page dynamically chenged befor)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".removeTime").live("click",function(){
     alert("hello");
    });
});​
```