# How can I use jquery and webresource in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

I have downloaded latest version of jquery and added file to web resources. I have added this resource to the library of the form where I intended to use jquery, but when I tried to use simple function it didn't work. JQuery is on top of the library list.

I tried different approach with customizing quote form by adding web resource to a form with the following code:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>    

<form>
    <input type="file">
</form>

<script> 
    $(":file").change(function()
    {
        alert($(":file").val());
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this code in CRM I get this message "Error: '$' is undefined". If I save this code to i.e. index.html it works. I was following instructions from the links bellow but without success.

http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/using-jquery-in-crm-2011/
http://thecrmworld.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/how-to-add-jquery-support-to-crm-2011/

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what you are trying to do on which form and how, possibly provide some screencaps of it. You seem to be doing things correctly but in order to get to something we need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use external links as they are not reliable.
This post explains exactly how to bind jquery into your web resource. 
[how do you add jquery in a html page as a web resource in dynamics crm 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232968/how-do-you-add-jquery-in-a-html-page-as-a-web-resource-in-dynamics-crm-2011)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you don't have to import the library. If you use parent.$ you are going to use the jQuery library of Dynamics CRM.

If you want to try the Javascript before uploading to a web resource follow this link
https://dynamicscrm365helper.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-try-crm-javascript-before.html
You only have to change the Xrm.Page.getAttribute()...with

```
parent.$('input#file').on('change',function() {
parent.$('input#file').val()
})
```