# Place a div above another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs inside another div (`#video-wrapper`).

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="video-wrapper col-lg-2">
        <div class="video-thumbnail">
            <img src="img/img.jpg">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play video-play"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign video-info"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="video-description">
            <p class="title">See and Sea...</p>
            <div class="video-upload-info">
                <p class="by">Franschisil</p>
                <p class="pubdate">4 days ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.video-wrapper {
}

.video-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 110px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.video-description {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to hide the `#video-description`, and diplay it above the `#video-thumbnail` when the `.video-info` is clicked. How do I achieve this? Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

**update**

This is how I want it to look like before I click the info:

[image]

And when its clicked to be like this:

[image]

** update ** 
When applied `position:absolute` the `.video-description` width shrinks in size if there are less alphabets :

[image]

Comment: to show info, you can achive this with jQuery and to display info above thumbnail you can achive this with position: absolute in your css

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: @charlietfl i did try using overflow:hidded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this in CSS:

```
.video-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-description {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.video-info{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.video-info').click(function(){
    $('.video-description').fadeToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/arr6LLdc/3/)

Comment: I did tried using `position:absolute`, but the width of `.video-description` shrinks if the there are less words. I have updated with the image.

Comment: Because of that I set `width: 100%;` also.

Comment: If I set the width to 100%, the width exceeds the parent div.

Comment: I update my answer, try [this new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/arr6LLdc/3/) :)

Comment: Yes it seems fine. But I am trying to achieve the same width of `.video-thumbnail` for `.video-description`. How would I do that? Lastly in your code, it would be better to use `$(this)`, since it will have other videos too.

Comment: You only need to remove `padding: 5px;`, and in jQuery code use `$(this).closest('.video-wrapper').find('.video-description').fadeToggle();` [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/arr6LLdc/4/).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with some simple [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

I've created two examples for you:

[image]

## [DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/04hLbxa1/)

[image]

## [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rhodprru/)

Where I use the following jQuery:

```
// DEMO 1
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info').click(function() {
        $('.video-description').slideToggle();        
    });
});

// DEMO 2
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $('.info').click(function() {
        $('.overlay').slideToggle();  
        if (!clicked) {
            $('.info').animate({top: "115px"}, 500);
            clicked = true;
        } else {
            $('.info').animate({top: "0px"}, 500);
            clicked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

In both demos, you will find all the necessary HTML, CSS and jQuery. If you study the code carefully, you should be able to replicate the effects yourself. Don't forget to [include jQuery in your document.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232968/how-do-you-add-jquery-in-a-html-page-as-a-web-resource-in-dynamics-crm-2011/5263297#5263297)

Comment: Its really interesting. But I am using bootstrap to use its `col` classes to get a responsive page.

Comment: Maybe this is not what you are looking for, but I loved the way the answer is shown.

Comment: @Kakar This code should also work with bootstrap if you make some minor adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this

Try the below code:

```
jQuery(".video-description").on('click',function(){
  jQuery(".video-description").insertBefore(jQuery(".video-thumbnail"));

});
```

Hope it helps....!